# Dart - How does one dart project import code from another dart project without using pub?

Tags: dart, dart-webui, dart-pub

Suppose I have two dart projects

Project A contains code that uses web component to create bunch of UI widget (similar to https://github.com/kevmoo/widget.dart)

Project B contains my front end code that would reuse the UI widget I created in project A.

If I dont want to publish my project A to pub, is there anyway to link project B to project A without manually copying files from project A into B?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a look at this section in the `pub` documentation: Path Dependencies:

http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/dependencies.html#path-packages

Suppose `project_a` had a library file called `myprojecta.dart`

```
dependencies:
  project_a:
    path: /Users/me/project_a   <-- root of project a
```

In your code, you would import `project_a` using

```
import 'package:project_a/myprojecta.dart'
```

Note - if you don't want to publish your project to pub, you can always use `git` as a dependency rather than `path` dependency - this lets other people in your team use your projects without relying upon *your* filesystem layout.

Comment: You should also note that you never have to publish your application when you use Pub. Above all other things, Pub is for consuming packages from pub.dartlang.org, git, your filesystem, or even from somewhere else in your package.
Check out http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/ for an idea of all the things Pub helps you do.

Comment: Good clarification.  Yes, publishing to pub.dartlang.org is only required if you want to actually make your package public.

Comment: You can find [git dependency examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68023976/496176)