# How to use my dart packages private and not show on pub dart lang?

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-pub

I have dart packages that I don't want to publish to pub because of my company agreement. How to use my dart packages for only my company and not show on pub dart lang?

I've looked up on this link https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/1050 but still need more information about that.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you publish a package to https://pub.dartlang.org it will show up. There is no way around that.

Alternatives.

You can use

- path dependencies to packages stored on a local or network drive for example.
- Git dependencies to packages stored in a Git repository

  - on a local or network drive
  - hosted on GitHub, GitLab, or any other Git server
- run your own private Pub server.

See also

- https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dependencies
- https://github.com/dart-lang/pub_server

Comment: The pub_server repository is archived

Answer (score 53):

Günter Zöchbauer answer is correct but he hasn't provided it with examples.

So to use pub/package/lib without publishing on pub.dev :

**1. Local - Save in some local folder**

```yaml
dependencies:
  library_name:
   path: /path/to/library_name
```

---

**2. Hosted - Pushed on Github, Gitlab etc.**

```yaml
dependencies:
  library_name:
   git: https://github.com/username/library_name
```

Or to target specific branch

```yaml
dependencies:
  library_name:
   git:
    url: https://github.com/username/library_name.git
    ref: dev    #branch name
```

Or to target specific commit

```yaml
dependencies:
  library_name:
   git:
    url: https://github.com/username/library_name.git
    ref: e234072340    #commit reference id
```

Where '*library_name*' has to be the same as the '*name*' declared in pubspec.yaml of that pub.

Comment: git submodule is another possibility

Comment: What will happen if github repository is private. Do I need to provide a user name and password?

Comment: You can also specify folder: `path: packages/packageA`

Answer (score 6):

local :

To handle that, pub supports path dependencies.

```
dependencies:
  transmogrify:
    path: /Users/me/transmogrify
```

This says the root directory for transmogrify is /Users/me/transmogrify.

See :
https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dependencies

Comment: You will have to declare `publish_to: none` in you `pubspec.yaml` file, because using a path dependency is not allowed in a publishable library.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at https://onepub.dev

It's a private package repository written specifically for dart.

You can publish to OnePub in a few commands

```
dart pub global activate onepub
onepub login
cd myproject
onepub pub private
dart pub publish
```

To add a dependency hosted on OnePub

```
cd aproject
onepub pub add myproject
dart pub get
```

In a CI/CD pipeline onepub allows you to export/import a security token to provide authentication.

There is a free version for small teams.

Answer (score 1):

You can also let someone else run the pub server (as a service):
https://cloudsmith.io/l/dart-repository/

Although it's commercial (paid) for private repositories, it's free for public and open-source repositories. If you're looking for a serverless managed solution, it's the only alternative (as of writing).